# How to connect 2 laptops using wireless for sharing their screen ? (remote desktop)

Tags: remote-desktop, wireless

I want to connect 2 laptops with wireless connection that I want to connect to ones using another one. by connect I mean I want to use second laptop's desktop but with out logging out from it. something like TeamViewer but with wireless and router, not internet. Remote Desktop of Windows log out from the target laptop and I don't want it. 
pleas help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know the good old VNC? 
You need to run the VNC server on the target laptop in order to access it with the client laptop.

Check out the following links for further details.

VNC Server / Client UltraVNC: http://www.uvnc.com/

VNC at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing